# Local environment for Magento 2, on Mac is it a thing?

Tags: magento2, error, local

Is anybody using local environment for Magento 2, on Mac OS?

When i try to run my local environment using xampp i get this error on localhost/magento2/setup

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: The file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/var/.regenerate" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/var/.regenerate): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(172): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/Applications/X...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php(99): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->delete('/var/.regenerat...') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(110): Magento\Framework\Code\GeneratedFiles->cleanGeneratedFiles() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(209): Magento\Framework\App in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 382
```

There seems to be next to none information about it online, i found one dude who had this problem, but his solution is outdated, there have been some php changes it seems like.

I don't expect you guys to replicate this problem but, i want do know if Magento developers is doing it local and push using git, or it all is on a server running linux?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same but I highly recommend https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/ for developing on MacOS.

As you're already using local services I'd suggest stopping Apache and MySQL as you will run into conflicts.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of problems with setting up valet+ i have some problems that have open threads on the github with no solution yet, Problems with Homebrew and php 7.1.x, but thanks for the recommendation, i will keep an eye on it